# Can't get data out of Axios

Tags: react-native, axios

Can't get my data from the request out of Axios.  My console log prints the correct but when I try to set it to a variable or return it I get nothing.

```
static getGroupByID(groupID) {
    var self = this;
    var group = '';

    axios.post((GRAPHQL_END_POINT), {
      query: print(Queries.GET_GROUP_BY_ID),
      variables: {
        groupID: groupID
      }`enter code here`
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.data.getGroup.name);
        self.group = res.data.data.getGroup.name;
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
    return group;
  }
```

Comment: There may be a scope issue with internal variables, have you tried returning the part of res that you want and then setting the entire axios expression to a variable: `self.group = axios.post(...`

Comment: set the value in state, or use await

Answer (score 0):

```
static getGroupByID(groupID) {
    var self = this;
    var group = '';

    return axios.post((GRAPHQL_END_POINT), { <-- Return your promise
      query: print(Queries.GET_GROUP_BY_ID),
      variables: {
        groupID: groupID
      }`enter code here`
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.data.getGroup.name);
        return res.data.data.getGroup.name; <--- Return your data and use getGroupById(...).then(...)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is async, your function returns an empty `group = ''`, set the value in state or use await. The function returns before the query finish, you can for the query to finish using async/await.

```
static async getGroupByID(groupID) {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(GRAPHQL_END_POINT, {
      query: print(Queries.GET_GROUP_BY_ID),
      variables: {
        groupID: groupID
      }
    });

    const { data } = await res;
    return data;

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Or you can just return the promise and handle it where you are calling the function.

```
static getGroupByID(groupID) {
  return axios.post(GRAPHQL_END_POINT, {
    query: print(Queries.GET_GROUP_BY_ID),
    variables: {
      groupID: groupID
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for writing this out.  I tried your async function but all I receive is this...  { _40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null }  It is the same for whatever I change the result to.

Comment: is it different from what you get when you console log in your function?

Comment: Yeah with my function I just get a blank line printed in the console.

Comment: what type of data, do you expect from the backend?

Comment: Just a integer.  I don't think the backend is the problem because I can log the result from the function in my method but I cant save it or return it.

Comment: do `console.log(res.status)` before the return statement

Comment: the response is valid, and the data comes from the backend, do you have access to your backend?

Comment: I do have access to the back-end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195149/discussion-between-junius-l-and-peter-cooke).